# Timer with react hooks doesn't update after re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a timer with React hooks. It's a simple component that is used in a quiz. Each question has a defined duration so the timer should start at this duration and start decreasing one second at a time. My problem is that the component does what is supposed to do, but when I go to the next question the state doesn't initialize to the duration passed in the props but continues with the counter...

```
  const Timer = ({ duration }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(duration);
  const timer = useRef();
  debugger;
  console.log("counter: " + counter);
  const setTimer = () => {
    if (counter <= duration) {
      setCounter(counter - 1);
    }
  };
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => setTimer(), 1000);
    return () => {
      if (timer.current) {
        console.log("ClearInterval in Timer");
        clearTimeout(timer.current);
      }
    };
  }, [counter]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>time left {counter} seconds</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

I'm rendering the Timer component from the Card component:

```
import React from "react";
import QuizButton from "../QuizButton/QuizButton";
import Timer from "../Timer/Timer";
import "./styles.css";

const QuizQuestion = ({ question, responses, checkAnswerFn, duration }) => (
  <article className='card'>
    <header>
      <Timer duration={duration} />
    </header>
    <div>
      <p>{question}</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      {responses.map((response, i) => {
        return (
          <QuizButton key={i} onClick={checkAnswerFn(response)}>
            {response}
          </QuizButton>
        );
      })}
    </footer>
  </article>
);

export default QuizQuestion;
```

Does anyone know why the state is not initialized to duration after the question re-renders?

Comment: State is not supposed to reinitialize for subsequent renders, that's kind of the whole point. Are you meaning that the component `Timer` should re-mount?

Comment: No, I want the next time Timer is rendered because the next Question is rendered, the duration starts at the value passed in the props

Comment: I really don't think you do... If `counter` gets reset to `duration` every time `Timer` renders, it will never decrement. Calling `setCounter` triggers a re-render for `Timer`.

Comment: If you don't want it to remount, but only to reset `counter` when `duration` changes, then maybe you could set up a `useEffect` to run when the `duration` prop changes? But if the `duration` value doesn't change each question then that won't work either.

Comment: Thanks Brian, you are right, I re-render the component every time I use setCounter. I thought that once I re-render Timer again with a different props value then useState will reinitialize the state to the value passed in the props... but I think I didn't understand completely the lifecycle of the components...

Comment: Yeah both a change in props and a change in state have the same effect on a component - a re-render. `useState` only pays attention to the initial value passed in on the first render, after that it will never re-initialize. You would have to do it manually with an effect or some other logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATED 2 - Added Question Array and Question based timer data**

> **UPDATED 1 - I THINK IT WORKS NOW AS YOUR WISH TO TO BE LIKE**
>
> Summary - I have lifted some states up.

So the edited answer is: Since we need to resend new prop data to the Child Timer component while the trigger was based on the child component which I have demonstrated using a click from the child Timer component, we passed a function from the parent Question component to the child component which would be called on an onClick listener via the prop. Therefore the function updates the parent's (Question.js) state re-rendering the child (Timer.js) and passing new prop values whichever we have set as new. Rather than relaying on timer based change we also changed to data based trigger like the Question Data changed to invoke the useEffect.

I hope the explanation works and and solved your use case.

..

```
//Question.js    

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import "./styles.css";

const Question = () => {
  const questionPool = [
    { number: 1, text: "lorem", timer: 6 },
    { number: 2, text: "lorem", timer: 10 },
    { number: 3, text: "lorem", timer: 20 },
    { number: 4, text: "lorem", timer: 3 },
    { number: 5, text: "lorem", timer: 12 }
  ];
  const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(questionPool[0].timer);
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(
    questionPool[0].number
  );


  const resetCount = (newQuestion) => {
    newQuestion < questionPool.length + 1
      ? setCurrentQuestion(newQuestion)
      : setCurrentQuestion(1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (questionPool[currentQuestion]) {
      setCountDown(questionPool[currentQuestion].timer);
    } else {
      setCountDown(questionPool[0].timer);
    }
  }, [currentQuestion]);

  return (
    <>
      <Timer
        duration={countDown}
        resetCountDown={resetCount}
        questionNumber={currentQuestion}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Question;
```

....

```
//Timer.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Timer = ({ duration, resetCountDown, questionNumber}) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(duration);
  let interval = null;
  useEffect(() => {
    const myInterval = () => {
      if (counter > 1) {
        setCounter((state) => state - 1);
      } else if (counter !== 0) {
        setCounter(0);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    };
    interval = setInterval(myInterval, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!interval) {
      setCounter(duration);
    }
  }, [questionNumber]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        time left {counter} seconds For Question: {questionNumber}
      </p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => resetCountDown(questionNumber + 1)}>
        next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timer;
```

[CodeSandbox Extending from  @Adolfo Onrubia to match your use case](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-currying-2jerq?file=/src/index.js)

Check if this helps.

********* DEPRECATED BELOW *******************

If you still want to dynamically add timer component, I think you need to push in a whole react component in the prop and have the component which is pushing a new component re-render so the child will render itself and a new question with a new component can appear.

In short,

- Your QuestionsArray[{OBJECT WITH QUESTION DETAILS}] is in your main app.
- Your have a useState like :

> const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] =
> useState(QuestionArray[0]);

And whenever a next button is pushed. You do

> setCurrentQeustion(QuestionArray[NewIndex]);

Thus your master component App Components' State re-renders on **useEffect** of **currentQuestion** and passes that to the Timer.js/child component causing it to rerender with new Timeout duration.

It may also be worthwhile to check on props.children so rather than just sending as a regular prop you pass as template like.

```
<Template>
 {currentQuestion}
</Template>
```

Comment: Thanks Fauzul, I have added the way I render the Timer component. if I understood correctly the way I've done it will not provide the output expected (everytime a new question is rendered the timer will start at the duration of the question)...

Comment: @Javip Added Question Array which have their own Time Counter Duration data.

Comment: Thanks Fauzul, with your response and the one from Adolfo Onrubia below, I managed to resolve the issue. As you mentioned, I solved it passing the id of the question to the Timer and using useEffect on it. As the id's are always different the timer updates the duration when the id changes... I posted my code below

Answer (score 1):

Look a bit complex to drive you how and why your code is not working as expected, but here is a working example just did it today, hope it helps to point you in the right direction:

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(15000);

...


useEffect(() => {
    const myInterval = () => {
      if (counter > 1000) {
        setCounter(state => state - 1000)
      } else if (counter !== 0){
        setCounter(0);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    const interval = setInterval(myInterval, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [counter]);

...

console.log(counter); // 15000, 14000, 13000, ...
```

Comment: Hi Adolfo, thanks for the reply. My problem as I mentioned to Fauzul below, is that every question has its own duration. I render the Timer component, from the Question component passing in the props the duration. The issue I have is that when I reply the first question the timer for the second question doesn't re-start at duration... but to the counter of the previous question.

Comment: Ok! So, what if you add `duration` prop into `useEffect` dependency `[counter, duration]`, this way you can `setCounter` every time duration prop changes ;-)

Comment: Hi Adolfo, you pointed me in a correct direction, but that only works when duration is different every time. If I have 2 questions with the same duration the component doesn't re-start...

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the `setTimer` function is not allowing the `counter` to initialize. Let your function decrement the counter until and unless the counter value is greater than 0 otherwise initialize it with the `duration`. Replace your function with the following, it will help you initialize the timer back to the duration.

```
const setTimer = () => {
  setCounter(counter > 0  ? counter - 1 : duration);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fauzul and Adolfo, I finally solved my issue.

I pass the id of the question to the props of the timer, and using the useEffect hook, everytime the id changes the counter gets updated to the duration...

QuizQuestion.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import QuizButton from "../QuizButton/QuizButton";
import Timer from "../Timer/Timer";
import "./styles.css";

const QuizQuestion = ({ question, responses, checkAnswerFn, duration, id }) => (
  <article className='card'>
    <header>
      <Timer duration={duration} id={id} />
    </header>
    <div>
      <p>{question}</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      {responses.map((response, i) => {
        return (
          <QuizButton key={i} onClick={checkAnswerFn(response)}>
            {response}
          </QuizButton>
        );
      })}
    </footer>
  </article>
);

QuizQuestion.propTypes = {
  question: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  responses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  checkAnswerFn: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default QuizQuestion;
```

Timer.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Timer = ({ duration, id }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(duration);
  const timer = useRef();
  const setTimer = () => {
    if (counter > 0) {
      setCounter(counter - 1);
    }
  };
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => setTimer(), 1000);
    return () => {
      if (timer.current) {
        clearTimeout(timer.current);
      }
    };
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(duration);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>time left {counter} seconds</p>
    </div>
  );
};

Timer.propTypes = {
  duration: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default Timer;
```